# Brightness, altitude & azimuth for satellites?

Tags: observational-astronomy, amateur-observing, natural-satellites, satellite, night-sky

I'm using the [heavens-above website](https://heavens-above.com/AllSats.aspx) to identify a satellite I've seen several nights this week.

The question is related to how I can search the satellites table with the information I can provide.

The page has a table that has the satellite name, `Brightness (mag)`, and *Time*, *Altitude*, and *Azimuth* for `Start` , `Highest point` and `End`. I don't know how brightness and altitude are measured, and I don't know how the start, highest, and end points are measured. In terms of *azimuth*, if I base it on [this compass](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ktB7I.png), and based on the time I saw it, I would have to say **NNE**.

With that said, last night I was sitting looking straight north. I first saw the satellite, literally moving directly over my head, at 7:33pm EST and stopped seeing it at a 7:36PM EST because it was too far. The satellite was going *North* and just a bit to the *East*.

My question: how can I use this information to search for the satellite in the table? Also, how do I know what's the *Brightness (mag)*? The satellite is so tiny that it's almost impossible to see with the naked eye.

Answer (score 1):

[Altitude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horizontal_coordinate_system) is measured in degrees above the horizon, from 0° on the horizon to 90° directly overhead.
Your fist appears about 10° wide at arm's length away from your eye.

Azimuth is measured along the horizon, usually with north 0°, east 90°, south 180° west 270°, and other directions (e.g. NNE, ENE) interpolated as in the compass image.

[Magnitude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apparent_magnitude) is a logarithmic scale in which the brightest stars are 0 or 1, and the faintest stars visible to the unaided eye are 4 or 5 (maybe 2 or 3 in a city, or 6 in a remote area).

Each row of Heavens-Above's table links to a sky chart showing their predicted path for that satellite pass.
The brightness listed in the main table is a maximum; the table under the sky chart shows a brightness for other points on the path.